# Inconsistency between confusion matrix and classified image

Tags: r, machine-learning, image-processing, random-forest

Due to computational limitations with my GIS software, I am trying to implement random forests in R for image classification purposes. My input is a multi-band TIFF image, which is being trained on an ArcGIS shapefile (target values 0 and 1). The code technically works and produces a valid output. When I view the confusion matrix I get the following:

```
     0    1    class.error
0    11    3    0.214285714
1    1    13    0.071428571
```

This is sensible for my data. However when I plot up the output of the image classification in my GIS software (the binary reclassified tiff with values 0 and 1), it predicts the training data with a 100% success rate. In other words there is no classification error with the output image. How is this the case when the confusion matrix indicates there are classification errors?

Am I missing something really obvious here? Code snippet below.

```
rf.mdl <- randomForest(x=samples@data[, names(PredMaps)], y=samples@data[, ValueFld], ntree=501, proximity=TRUE, importance=TRUE, keep.forest=TRUE,keep.inbag=TRUE)

ConfMat = rf.mdl$confusion
write.csv(ConfMat,file = "ConfMat1.csv")

predict(PredMaps, rf.mdl, filename=classifiedPath, type="response", na.rm=T, overwrite=T, progress="text")
```

I expected the output classified image to misclassify 1 of the Value=1 training points and misclassify 3 of the Value=0 training points based on what is indicated in the confusion matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Random Forest algorithm is a bagging method. This means it creates numerous weak classifiers, then has each weak classifier "vote" to create the end prediction. In RF, each weak classifier is one decision tree that is trained on a random sample of observations in the training set. Think of the random samples each decision tree is trained on as a "bag" of data.

What is being shown in the confusion matrix is something called "out-of-bag error" (OOB error). This OOB error is an accurate estimate of how your model would generalize to data it has never seen before (this estimate is usually achieved by testing your model on a withheld testing set). Since each decision tree is trained on only one bag from your training data, the rest of the data (data that's "outside the bag") can stand in for this withheld data.

OOB error is calculated by making a prediction for each observation in the training set. However, when predicting each individual observation, only decision trees whose bags *did not include that observation* are allowed to participate in the voting process. The result is the confusion matrix available after training a RF model.

When you predict the observations in the training set using the complete model, decision trees whose bags *did include each observation* are now involved in the voting process. Since these decision trees "remember" the observation they were trained on, they skew the prediction toward the correct answer. This is why you achieve 100% accuracy.

Essentially, you should trust the confusion matrix that uses OOB error. It's a robust estimate of how the model will generalize to unseen data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought I had made an R coding error as it is the first time I have used R. This makes sense.